# layout height issue with weight and wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout

My view is like:

```
<LinearLayout 
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

It will give 50dp to `TextView` and rest of area to `RecyclerView`.
But if items in `RecyclerView` are less than, say 1 or 2, then it should shrink to the height of it's child views other wise behave like layout specifies. Can any one help??

Comment: Why not use a RelativeLayout and use the attribute layout_below? or you don't want that?

Comment: thanks @HusseinElFeky

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option would be to change `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` of the root view dynamically. When the `RecyclerView`has a low amount of children, then set `LinearLayout` params to:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.setParams(params);
```

otherwise, leave as it is.

It is very easy to detect if `RecyclerView` should be wrapped. Obtain LinearLayout height:

```
int height = layout.getTop() - layout.getBottom()
```

If this height is lower than the expected maximum height (screen height or other predefined value).

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be using RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```